# How to create an unlimited stream endpoint in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'd like to create:

- an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web Application in VS2017 with one HttpGet Endpoint
- The endpoint should stream random Values between 0 and 255
- Every 20ms the value should change.
- The Client should never stop reading the stream and as fast as possible get the new values.

So far this is my Code:

**Client**

```
    public async Task SubscribeToUpdates()
    {
        this.subscribe = false;
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(Constants.SubscribeEndpoint);

            using (var rdr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (!rdr.EndOfStream && !subscribe)
                {
                    var result = rdr.ReadLine();
                    var json = JObject.Parse(result);
                    this.HandleUpdateResult(json); // todo
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TO do: log exception
        }
    }
```

**Server, not working**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Task PushStreamContent()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
        var sourceStream = randomStream();
        return sourceStream.CopyToAsync(HttpContext.Response.Body);
    }

    public static Stream randomStream()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rnd.News(0,255));
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
```

Question:

- How to rewrite Server function to create the unlimited stream?
- Other solutions are also welcome, as long as they keep in mind that they are .net core conform and enable the client to get as fast as possible the latest information.

**Working Full .Net Version**

I've managed to write the Code for .net Standard, but not for .net core. Reason for this is that PushStreamContent does not exist in .net core :/.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage PushStreamContent()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

        response.Content =
            new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
            {
                var plotter = new Plotter();

                while (true)
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random()
                        writer.WriteLine(rnd.Next(0,255));
                        stream.Flush();
                        Thread.Sleep(20);
                    }
                }
            });

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What's your client? Because you seem to be a bit confused as to how web services work. HTTP is basically a stateless protocol; it's geared to call-response. If you want to keep a connection open like this, you need to look at WebSockets.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention. It's a Xamarin App. It has a Textbox which should show the Random Value from the Server.

Comment: Yes your better of using low level Sockets, it's basically http but then just only bytes, no http headers etc. Otherwise better idea to reduce data= only send an initial seed to the client. You'd only need to send it once and be able to generate random value every time. And you'd be able to check the validity of that value Serverside if you'd keep amount you generate a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the previous Answer from "Mike McCaughan" and "Joel Harkes", i've rethinked the communcation process and switched from REST to Websockets.

You can find a good Example how to use WebSockets in .net Core (and Xamarin.Forms) [here](https://github.com/NVentimiglia/Websockets.PCL). You will have to use the Nuget Package "Websockets.PCL".

Comment: I know you have found the solution, but it seems that HTTP endpoint just to provide random values, and not truly random is a bit excessive. Could you not do just the same `new Random().Next(0, 255)` (or equivalent) on the client without having do this over HTTP?